# Context confusion (adjectives & tenses)

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, adjectives, conversation

Are the following sentences grammatically right and applicable ??

1- The country didn't take procedures as firm as it is in other countries.

2- The country didn't take procedures as firm as it has been in other countries.

3- The country didn't take procedures as firmly as others countries did

Comment: I think the word **precautions** in your sentences would be better than the word **procedures**. However, if you want to use that word instead, I think it would be more natural to say _**implement** procedures_ instead of _**take**_ them.

Comment: _Procedures_  is plural, so _it_ doesn't fit. (3) is the best option, but I agree with Kman3 that _implement_ or _apply_ would be a better choice of verb..

Comment: @Kman3  Thank you I will consider to use " implement" .But what about the structure of sentence number 1 and 2 , grammatically speaking.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Thank you  for the explanation ,but what about the structure of sentence number 1 and 2.

Comment: As I told you, _it_ doesn't go with _procedures_. You would have to say _The country didn't apply procedures as firm as those that other countries applied_ (where _those_ refers to _procedures_).

Comment: @Kate bunting  I totally understand what you wrote . Can I use "as they are " instead of " as those "  ,so the sentence become     " The country didn't apply procedures as firm as they are in others"

Comment: No, _they are_ doesn't fit.